# Cannot login after update to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

After I updated to Ubuntu 14.04, I am not able to login to Ubuntu.

Whenever I enter my password, my screen flashes for a couple of seconds and goes back to the login screen. I have tried over and over again but the same thing happens.

I can't login through the guest session either - whenever I click login, the screen flashes and goes back to the login screen again.

What do I do? I'm really confused and stuck and I need to fix this problem REALLY soon!

Thanks!

Comment: boot to recovery mode, drop to a root shell, and make sure everything in your home directory is owned by your user. If that fails, try resetting unity - http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Since it happens with guest sessions too, the problem is probably not home directory related. I would check the lightdm config files.

Comment: you can look at the logs, but, it takes longer to debug a failed upgrade then it does to do a fresh install. Your data in /home will be preserved as long as you do NOT format yout root partition.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fairly new to Terminal and Ubuntu. Are there any specific commands that would help me do what I need to do?

Comment: Someone please give me step-by-step directions on how to fix this problem please !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by correcting the ownership of the file: ~/.Xauthority.
Just open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo chown `whoami`.`whoami` -R .Xauthority
```

Comment: Sorry! Didn't work. Ubuntu just crashes when I do this. Is it possible if you could answer this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488144/uninstall-ubuntu-14-04-without-recovery-disk-usb-help-needed-urgently

Answer (score 0):

[ I realize this is a long dead thread, I am primarily providing an answer for my future self to find after updating Ubuntu and having it once again break the install ]

If you are running Ubuntu within a VM, you most likely need to reinstall your virtual machine tools.

Ubuntu update/upgrade will have clobbered the video drivers.  I removed the Ubuntu installed nVidia* packages, however that was quite likely not necessary.

You could try removing/correcting permissions on the ~/.Xauthority file, however I suspect you will not see and change in behavour.

General steps for re-installing virtual machine tools is as follows:

1. start guest OS (Ubuntu)
2. select "Reinstall VM Tools"
3. login in via console (Ctl-Alt-F1 from the GUI login screen)
4. sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
5. cd /mnt ; sudo ./install
6. follow prompts - repair/re-install as prompted.
7. reboot.